# Why I can't upload files without chmod 777?

Tags: ftp, chmod

I was not able to upload files on my site (cent OS 6 VPS). The path where web files should be uploaded is `/var/www/html`.

The permissions of directories were `755` and of files were `644`.

But when I chmoded all files and directories in `/var/www` to `777` recursively then I was able to upload to `/var/www/html`

I am running WordPress. Isn't it a security issue to chmod all files and folders to `777`? Also, if I chmod them back to `755`, I cannot upload any files.

Comment: You need to speak to your management and get them to provide some education on the tools that you are using. This is incredibly basic stuff that any professional at any level should know or be able to find out easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix permissions in CentOS \`/var/www/html\` directory?](http://serverfault.com/questions/555452/how-can-i-fix-permissions-in-centos-var-www-html-directory)

Comment: @JakeGloud Yes but this is some what different :)

Answer (score 3):

You should never set files & folders to `777` permissions which basically means 100% of anyone with access to your server—or even via WordPress—can read, write & execute scripts.

The reason you are running into this issue is that the user ownership of the WordPress directory does not match the user that is running Apache. Of the Apache user does not own the files in a web root, it will not be able to write or execute.

So the solution is to figure out who the Apache web user is on your setup, and then set the WordPress install to be owned by that Apache web user.

To find out who is the Apache web user run this command look in the Apache environment variables file and find the `User` and `Group`.  In Ubuntu it is located here:

```
nano /etc/apache2/envvars
```

And it is the line:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

Under CentOS it seems like it will be here, but I have not touched CentOS in years:

```
nano /etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: Seems like you are in over your head.  Assuming good faith, I added some details. But you might want to get some help from your ISP's tech support.  Also, SPAMming questions will not get you answers & will get you banned.

Comment: I used
    
    sudo chown -R apache /var/www/html/
and changed permissions back to 755 dirs and 644 (files), still I cant upload..